# How to replace the first, middle, and last occurrences of a symbol with different symbols?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file containing many `/`'s per line, e.g.:

```
This/is/an/example.
This/is/another/example/to/read.
Read/this/example.
Last/example.
```

I need to replace the first occurrence of `/` on each line with `\BEGIN`, the last occurrence of `/` on each line with `\END`, and all of the remaining occurrences of `/` with `\MIDDLE`. E.g., the above file would become this:

```
This\BEGINis\MIDDLEan\ENDexample.
This\BEGINis\MIDDLEanother\MIDDLEexample\MIDDLEto\ENDread.
Read\BEGINthis\ENDexample.
Last\BEGINexample.
```

How can I replace this symbol in this way using BASH or other tools available on Linux, such as `grep`?

Comment: are there only 3 occurrences or more ?

Comment: There might be fewer. I have updated the example to show what happens with 1 or 2 occurrences. If no occurrences appears on a line, then nothing changes with that line.

Comment: What language do you plan on using ? bash-script ? php ? regexp ? you should include all this information in your questions and tags - otherwise you reduce the chances that the relevant people will track your question and help you.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `sed` (you need `sed -E` for the extended regexps on mac OSX):

```
sed -E 's/\//\\BEGIN/; s/\/([^/]+$)/\\END\1/; s/\//\\MIDDLE/g'
```

It works because the first `s` command doesn't have the `g` (global) flag so only the first occurrence of `/` is replaced. The second `s` replaces the last occurrence by virtue of `$`, and finally the last substitution replaces all the remaining forward slashes. The order of substitutions is important: if there is one forward slash you get `//BEGIN`, if there is another you get `//END`.

Comment: Note that you can use anything as a delimiter for `sed`'s `s` command, not only slashes. So this is more readable: `sed -E 's:/:\\BEGIN:; s:/([^/]+$):\\END\1:; s:/:\\MIDDLE:g'`

Comment: This replaces the first `/`, but all of the other `/`'s are replaced with `\MIDDLE`. None of the `/`'s becomes `\END`.

Answer (score 1):

You might try grepping ^([a-zA-Z]+)[](.*)[]([a-zA-Z]+)$
and replace it with $1 /BEGIN $2 /END $3

And then grep for all \ and replcae them with /MIDDLE

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS=/ read -a f; do (
    set -- "${f[@]}"
                    printf "$1"                       && shift
    (( $# ))     && printf "\\BEGIN$1"                && shift
    (( $# > 1 )) && printf "\\MIDDLE%s" "${@:1:$#-1}" && shift $(( $#-1 ))
    (( $# ))     && printf "\\\\END$1"
                    printf "\n"
    )
done < input.txt
```

The input is read one line at a time, splitting each line on the / character and storing the result in the positional parameters of a subshell. The first field (which we assume to exist) is printed unconditionally, and each remaining field is printed preceded by the correct delimiter. The terminating newline is printed unconditionally.

(I'm not entirely sure why the double double-backslash is required for END. Without it, I only printed the D of END.)

Comment: This script deletes `/`'s that appear at the end of lines.